# Simulating the behavior of the linux command “who” using GLib package - Valgrind error

Tags: c, data-structures, valgrind, glib

It fetches the details of the users who have logged in the system and print their details and store them in suitable data structure and finally display.
This is the code I've written. The output is proper but I get 'definitely lost' and 'indirectly lost' in the valgrind check.
Tried so much checking the leak.
Can anyone help me in clearing them. It'd be useful if they tell how it'd have been avoided while writing the prgoram itself.
**All the necessary header files are included**

```
void disp(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer userdata)
{
printf("%-10s",(char*)key);
g_slist_foreach((GSList*)value, (GFunc)displ, NULL);
printf("\n");
g_free(key);
g_slist_free((GSList*)value);
}

void displ(gpointer value, gpointer userdata)
{
printf("%-25s ", (char *)value);
g_free(value);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if(argc > 1)
{
    printf("Too many input arguments. \n");
    exit(1);
}

GHashTable* hash = NULL;
hash = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
GSList* list = NULL;

struct utmpx *ret = NULL;
struct passwd *uentry = NULL;
char *id = NULL;
char *name = NULL;
char *hostid = NULL;

while((ret = getutxent())!= NULL)
{
    if(USER_PROCESS == ret->ut_type)
    {       
        /*fetch userid for this user*/
        uentry = getpwnam(ret->ut_user);
        if (NULL == uentry)
        {
            printf("No user found. \n");
            return 0;
        }
        else 
        {   
            /* Create new list for each user */
            list = NULL;
            id = strdup(ret->ut_user);
            name = strdup(uentry->pw_gecos);
            hostid = strdup(ret->ut_host);
            list = g_slist_append(list, name);
            list = g_slist_append(list,hostid);

            g_hash_table_insert(hash, id, list);
                        }
    }
}
/* printing the details of respective users */
g_hash_table_foreach(hash, (GHFunc)disp, NULL);
/*freeing memory created for Hash Table */
g_hash_table_destroy(hash);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code in post instead of image ?

Comment: @ParhamAlvani Check now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to free all memory was used by Glib you must use it's specific functions for doing this because Glib use reference counting method for freeing objects. I changed your code as follow and all used memory was freed successfully.

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <utmpx.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void displ(gpointer value, gpointer userdata)
{
    printf("%-25s ", (char *) value);
}

void dell(gpointer value)
{
    g_free(value);
}

void del_list(gpointer value)
{
    g_slist_free_full((GSList*)value, (GDestroyNotify)dell);
}

int disp_del(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer userdata)
{
    printf("%-10s",(char*)key);
    g_slist_foreach((GSList*)value, (GFunc)displ, NULL);
    printf("\n");
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        printf("Too many input arguments. \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    GHashTable* hash = NULL;
    hash = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, (GDestroyNotify)g_free, (GDestroyNotify)del_list);
    GSList* list = NULL;

    struct utmpx *ret = NULL;
    struct passwd *uentry = NULL;
    char *id = NULL;
    char *name = NULL;
    char *hostid = NULL;

    while ((ret = getutxent())!= NULL) {
        if(USER_PROCESS == ret->ut_type) {
            /* fetch userid for this user */
            uentry = getpwnam(ret->ut_user);
            if (NULL == uentry) {
                printf("No user found. \n");
                return 0;
            } else {
                /* Create new list for each user */
                list = NULL;
                id = strdup(ret->ut_user);
                name = strdup(uentry->pw_gecos);
                hostid = strdup(ret->ut_host);
                list = g_slist_append(list, name);
                list = g_slist_append(list, hostid);
                g_hash_table_insert(hash, id, list);
            }
        }
    }
    /* printing the details of respective users */
    g_hash_table_foreach_remove(hash, (GHRFunc)disp_del, NULL);
    /*freeing memory created for Hash Table */
    g_hash_table_remove_all(hash);
    g_hash_table_destroy(hash);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Was still getting "still reachable", and "possibly lost" errors. Then after some browsing a page, I used bash on these 2 commands: $export G_SLICE=always-malloc $export G_DEBUG=gc_friendly. All errors vanished. Does this mean that those were system-related memory leaks?

Comment: I think this mean gnome library (glib) use some memory management method that not system friendly, for example I think glib use reference counting method for memory management.